# Regex match only if multiple patterns found (python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract data from sentences such as:

```
"monthly payment of 525 and 5000 drive off"
```

using a python regex search function: re.search()

My regex query string is as follows for down payment:

```
match1 = "(?P<down_payment>\d+)\s*(|\$|dollars*|money)*\s*" + \
         "(down|drive(\s|-)*off|due\s*at\s*signing|drive\s*-*\s*off)*"
```

My problem is that it matches the wrong numerical value as down payment, it gets both 525, and 5000.

How can I improve my regex string such that it only matches an element if another element is successfully matched as well?

In this case, for example, both **5000** and **drive-off** matched so we can extract 5000 as down_payment, but 525 did not match with the any down payment values, so it should not even consider the 525.

[Clearer explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/AmPsCX/1)

Comment: Remove the final asterisk to make the right-hand side context obligatory. Check https://regex101.com/r/bm8EHE/1. What was the point of making it optional?

Comment: You can right some conditions based `group` values.

Comment: Please clarify the requirements or let know if my suggestion works for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew very new at regex and I misunderstood how it works. I thought it grabs parts of patterns too... that extra asterix was a typo I should use a + or remove it instead. thank you

Comment: So, the first numbered capturing group (`(|\$|dollars*|money)*`) can be still missing, right? And the last one is obligatory.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, that part is optional

Comment: Now, it is all clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you want to match a *sequence of patterns*. In order to make sure the trailing patterns are taken into account, they cannot be all optional. Look, `\s*`, `(|\$|dollars*|money)*`, `\s*`, `(down|drive(\s|-)*off|due\s*at\s*signing|drive\s*-*\s*off)*` can match empty strings.

I suggest removing the final `*` quantifier to match *exactly one occurrence* of the pattern:

```
(?P<down_payment>\d+)\s*(?:\$|dollars*|money)?\s*(down|drive[\s-]*off|due\s*at\s*signing|drive\s*-*\s*off)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bm8EHE/1)

Also note that I contracted a `(\s|-)` group into a character class `[\s-]` as you only alternate *single* char patterns, and also turned `(|\$|dollars*|money)*` into a non-capturing optional group `(?:\$|dollars*|money)?` that matches just 1 or 0 occurrences of `$`, `dollar(s)` or `money`.